# Why is a Hello World angular app 300 megabytes?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I'm an experienced Java/Tomcat developer, experimenting with AngularJS for the first time. I don't know much about npm, node, yeoman, bower, etc. I followed a tutorial to download these tools and create a new AngularJS project.

I don't remember all the steps, but the part about creating the Angular project was this:

```
npm install generator-angular
yo angular
```

The resulting empty project is 307.9 megabytes.

By comparison, creating a new empty Tomcat application from IntelliJ is 45 kilobytes.

Am I doing something wrong? If not, does it seem reasonable that the 'lightweight' Angular project is thousands of times larger?

Comment: Looks like it's not just AngularJS project. Maybe you've installed the whole (or partly) MEAN stack inc. some dependency packages/modules (via npm (e.g. Express) to run the whole Nodejs server?

Comment: Also to be a fair comparison, for a Java application you need the JDK, which is also several 100 MB big nowadays. The Angular pendant of development stuff however is part of those 300 MB.

Comment: Yeah, but you only install the JDK once - not once per project. And unlike this Angular project, the JDK doesn't get need to be checked into version control, backed up, or shared with anybody.

Comment: I recommend you use the [angular/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli) and follow the [official tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial).

Comment: @Sébastien That does not work. When I run the "ng new angular-tour-of-heroes", I get this error: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:17
    constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = []) {
                                                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Comment: There is no reason the Angular CLI should not work: you should install it globally with `npm install -g @angular/cli` and start a new project. Make sure you have the latest LTS version of [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and npm.

Comment: @Sébastien I got this to work by upgrading NodeJS, but after creating the new project it's 301.9 megabytes.

Comment: Yes, that's normal ;)

Comment: @Sébastien Then why did you recommend it? How does that answer my question? Is there any way to create a small Angular project instead of a giant bloated one?

Answer (score 3):

This is because the NPM package manager downloads the necessary dependencies to the node_module folder.
AngularJS is very different from 2+. For example, from version 2 onwards, they all use TypeScript, and to be able to load and compile everything you need Angular to work, it requires many libraries. However, if you use NPM, you can use the command `npm run-build` which allows you to compile your view, generating an output folder called "output" or similar. In this way, those files are the ones that you should upload to your server, or give it importance.

Comment: But even from a development standpoint (not talking about deployment), the size and quantity of files is obnoxious. For instance, I've been waiting for the last 30 minutes while trying to import my project into version control.

Comment: You should exclude all the `node_modules/` content from version control. When you pull your project on another machine, you will download the dependencies with `npm install`.

Comment: Yes, you must exclude the node_modules folder, for example if you use GitHub, you can create a file called `.gitignore` and write in the following line "node_modules".
Then those who download the code must run the command `npm install` before running it.